# Extjs custom sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting, extjs, extjs6-classic

I'm having a problem in understanding how I can define my custom sorter function on Grid

I'm using Extjs 6.2.0 (**EDIT: see below, at the end of post**)

When I try to set up that on store like below:

```
 sorters: [{
    {
        sorterFn: function() {
            console.log("I'm running from store");
        }
    }
 }]
```

This runs only once, and actually this makes sense, because documentation says that those are initial sorters

I also tried using that on column

```
 dataIndex: 'category_name',
 sorter: {
     sorterFn: function() {
         console.log("I'm running from column");
     }
 }
```

and this function doesnt even run (console.log() not appearing in browser window )

**EDIT: It turned out that I'm not using 6.2.0 but 6.0, so sorry for such silly mistake..
Anyways, someone know how I can create custom sort function for column grid in that version ?**

Comment: [Ex.grid.column.Column.sorter](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-sorter): A Sorter, or sorter config object to apply **when the standard user interface sort gesture is invoked**. This is usually clicking this column header, but there are also menu options to sort ascending or descending. - Have you tried to invoke the user interface sort gesture?

Comment: You mean if I tried clicking column header in that second example ?
I did, nothing happens

Comment: Well, for me, it works: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1vv5

Comment: Indeed it works...

Comment: Ok, turned out that I wasn't using Extjs 6.2.0 but 6.0.2, and that version doesn't even have 'sorter' paramater in grid column
So sorry for such silly mistake

Do you know by a chance how to implement custom sort function in that version ?

Comment: Ok I managed to find a workaround for my problem
Thank You @Alexander for guiding me, I would not fix this issue without you posting fiddle.sencha

Answer (score 3):

Okay eveyrone, I managed to achieve what I wanted with "sortType" custom function defined on field in Model.

Thanks !